# What type of program would theoretically run this?

Tags: ms-access

I'm relatively new to programming, so Im not quite sure how this all works yet, but I had an idea for a program that would make my job easier and was wondering what program language or tool I needed to learn to go about making it. Basically this program puts together an assembly of hardware using a database and the user checking boxes or selecting multiple options to narrow down the hardware for a specific structure.

Specifically, I work in designing transmission line structures (the towers and poles carrying wires you see on the highways and farms). These structures require multiple assemblies of hardware including bolts, nuts, insulators, etc. All of these parts need to be sized, and currently we do this all by ourselves using specifications. This is a HUGE waste of time and often tedious so I want to make a program that will just give us the list of hardware after we select a few options about the structure (material of structure, wire type, connection type, etc.).

I hear that Microsoft Access could be a tool used to do this, but wasn't sure. Would using Access work? Or is there a better option?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: There are a lot of languages out there. it's bacially going to come to what you either are currently comfortable, or what your capacity to learn is going to be.  No matter what, this question is far to broad, and entirely opinion based. this is not the place for these sort of questions.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Gene. So where is the right place to ask this sort of question?

Comment: I would use Excel.  With the SUMIFS and VLOOKUP and COUNTIFS functions, you can accomplish great thing a without programming.  Once you have it working in Excel, you can consider if you want to move it to Access or if that seems difficult then find a simpler database system like FilemakerPro.   You can handle several hundred thousand records in a database in Excel quite nicely with or without programming.

Comment: Try http://www.accessforums.net/